# Notepad++ regex to find text between 2 strings on different lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I hope someone can help me with this, I think it is a fairly simple expression, but I cannot get it working.

I want to find and replace all text between 2 strings on different lines.

The text looks like this:

```
<vehicle>
    <component1 position="464.8416 118.8764 -817.1907" rotation="-177.5330 -70.8486 -180.0000"/>
    <configuration name="cover" id="1"/>
    <configuration name="fillVolume" id="1"/>
    <configuration name="wheel" id="1"/>
    <configuration name="fillUnit" id="1"/>
    <configuration name="trailer" id="1"/>
    <boughtConfiguration name="cover" id="1"/>
    <boughtConfiguration name="fillVolume" id="1"/>
    <boughtConfiguration name="wheel" id="1"/>
    <boughtConfiguration name="fillUnit" id="1"/>
    <boughtConfiguration name="trailer" id="1"/>
    <attacherJoints comboDirection="-1"/>
    <fillUnit>
        <unit index="1" fillType="UNKNOWN" fillLevel="0.000000"/>
    </fillUnit>
    <cover state="0"/>
</vehicle>
```

All I want to do is remove everything including the `<vehicle>` and `</vehicle>` tags.

I have tried this:

```
(?s)^\t*<vehicle>(.|\r\n)*?<\/vehicle
```

and
this:

```
(?s-i)^<vehicle>.+?\<\/vehicle>.+?$\R
```

Both which I found googling but have tried and failed at getting these to work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It seems your line endings are not CRLF, hence you have no matches with the first regex. Use `(?s:.*?)` instead of `(.|\r\n)*?`

Comment: Try `<vehicle\s*>[\S\s]*?</vehicle\s*>` replace noting

Comment: Perfect: `<vehicle\s*>[\S\s]*?</vehicle\s*>` works, thanks very much!